# Joining string and tf.string to get a path

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am processing a csv file with the `tensorflow.Data` API. One feature in the csv is an image name. In order to load the image I need to build a path combining a base folder with the image name. However, since the image name is a tensor and the base folder is a string, I cannot join them with os.path.join. I include the code below.

```
def process_csv_data(folder_path, image_dimensions):
    width, height, channels = image_dimensions
    def map_function(raw_data):
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path,raw_data['image_name'].numpy().decode('utf-8'))
        image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=channels)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [width, height])
        image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
        return image
    return map_function
```

The former function is used as follows:

```
    raw_csv_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        csv_path,
        batch_size=1,
        column_names=CSV_COLUMNS,
        shuffle=False)

    dataset = raw_csv_dataset.map(
         process_csv_data(folder_path, image_dimensions, mode),
         num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

The code above produces this error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I have tried several approaches without success, like converting the folder name to a tensor and using `tf.strings.join`, or converting the `tf.string` to a standard python `string`. So, what would be a proper approach?

I'm using tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings with `+`:

```
image_path = folder_path + os.sep + raw_data['image_name']
```

Use [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) if you do need the path separator (in case it is not included in `folder_path`) and do not want to explicitly use `/` or `\`.

Comment: that results in another error: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [1]`  in line `image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)`

Comment: @magomar That is a different, unrelated error. `raw_data['image_name']` should be a "scalar" string (not an array of strings), otherwise you cannot pass to to `read_file`. That depends on the data itself (what `map_function` is receiving in `raw_data`). If it is an array with a single string (e.g. `['my_file.csv']`), you may fix it with `image = tf.io.read_file(tf.squeeze(image_path))`.

Comment: raw_data was an ordered dictionary, where 'image_name' is a feature (a column in the csv). Anyway, I fixed the error with `tf.reshape(image_path, [])`, which in this case is equivalent to tf.squeeze. To it is solved now, thanks.